# Is there a way to convert this pg.Pool query to Knex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to convert my pg pool queries to Knex and am having an issue with this query:

```
router.post('/register', validInfo, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, name, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = $1', [email]);
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
router.post('/register', validInfo, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, name, password } = req.body;
  try {
    //Check if user exists
    const user = await knex('users')
      .select('*')
      .where('user_email', $1, [email]);
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

When I create a new user in Postman I should receive an empty array but it's not working. What needs to change in order to match the first query?

Comment: http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where seems to indicate that you should just use `      .where('user_email', email);` -- have you tried that?

Comment: @MattMorgan I have tried that. Same result. The page just continuously reloads

Comment: I suggest you put some console.log statements or debug breakpoints in the code, EG before and after the DB call, to get more information about what's happening, and share that here.